# distinguish between cancellation of shielded task and current task

Tags: python, python-asyncio

While reading:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel
it seems that catching CancelledError is used for two purposes.

One is potentially preventing your task from getting cancelled.

The other is determining that something has cancelled the task you are awaiting.
How to tell the difference?

```
async def cancel_me():
    try:
        await asyncio.sleep(3600)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        raise
    finally:
        print('cancel_me(): after sleep')

async def main():
    task = asyncio.create_task(cancel_me())
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    task.cancel()
    try:
        await task
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        # HERE: How do I know if `task` has been cancelled, or I AM being cancelled?
        print("main(): cancel_me is cancelled now")
```

Comment: I didn't see, why you want to *distinguish*, **canceld is canceld**.

Comment: 1) A subtask I (this task) control is telling my subtasks to abort.
2) Something outside this task's control is telling it to abort.

Comment: Instead of *1) and 2)* raising `CancelledError` one of them raise a own exception `myPrivateCanceled`. Then you can catch two different signals.

Comment: Another solution here https://bugs.python.org/issue35945

Comment: Hey, curious if my answer should be accepted? Or are you waiting for a better way to resolve this?

Answer (score 9):

> How to tell the difference [between ourselves getting canceled and the task we're awaiting getting canceled]?

Asyncio doesn't make it easy to tell the difference. When an outer task awaits an inner task, it is delegating control to inner one's coroutine. As a result, canceling either task injects a [`CancelledError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-exceptions.html#asyncio.CancelledError) into the exact same place: the inner-most `await` inside the inner task. This is why you cannot tell the which of the two tasks was canceled originally.

However, it is possible to circumvent the issue by breaking the chain of `await`s and connecting the tasks using a completion callback instead. Cancellation of the inner task is then intercepted and detected in the callback:

```py
class ChildCancelled(asyncio.CancelledError):
    pass

async def detect_cancel(task):
    cont = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_future()
    def on_done(_):
        if task.cancelled():
            cont.set_exception(ChildCancelled())
        elif task.exception() is not None:
            cont.set_exception(task.exception())
        else:
            cont.set_result(task.result())
    task.add_done_callback(on_done)
    await cont
```

This is functionally equivalent to `await task`, except it doesn't await the inner `task` directly; it awaits a dummy future whose result is set after `task` completes. At this point we can replace the `CancelledError` (which we know must have come from cancellation of the inner task) with the more specific `ChildCancelled`. On the other hand, if the outer task is cancelled, that will show up as a regular `CancelledError` at `await cont`, and will be propagated as usual.

Here is some test code:

```py
import asyncio, sys

# async def detect_cancel defined as above

async def cancel_me():
    print('cancel_me')
    try:
        await asyncio.sleep(3600)
    finally:
        print('cancel_me(): after sleep')

async def parent(task):
    await asyncio.sleep(.001)
    try:
        await detect_cancel(task)
    except ChildCancelled:
        print("parent(): child is cancelled now")
        raise
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("parent(): I am cancelled")
        raise

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    child_task = loop.create_task(cancel_me())
    parent_task = loop.create_task(parent(child_task))
    await asyncio.sleep(.1)  # give a chance to child to start running
    if sys.argv[1] == 'parent':
        parent_task.cancel()
    else:
        child_task.cancel()
    await asyncio.sleep(.5)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Note that with this implementation, cancelling the outer task will not automatically cancel the inner one, but that may be easily changed with an explicit call to `child.cancel()`, either in `parent`, or in `detect_cancel` itself.

Asyncio uses a similar approach to [implement](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3396d1e0ca858065c5bb7e5a9737be6ffc4028f7/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L786) [`asyncio.shield()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.shield).

Comment: I have to give it a try. I was actually worried about the scenario involving a shielded task, so I guess reading it's implementation is what I need. BTW with the way shield() works, if the inner task raises an exception after it is cancelled, the exception is ignored - well, definitely not caught by anything outside the await shield(inner), because the inner task has gone it's own way now. It is a bit scary ;-) and undocumented. The exception *would* be caught if the inner task hasn't been cancelled.

Comment: @stach *BTW with the way shield() works, if the inner task raises an exception after it is cancelled, the exception is ignored* - I think you are misreading the implementation. It appears to return immediately only because it is a `def` rather than an `async def`. But the `_done_callback` set by `shield` does use `set_exception` to propagate the exception from the inner swaitable to the `outer` Future returned to the caller. Since the caller has to await the returned future (not doing so is an error and provokes a warning), the exception is always transferred.

Comment: @DimaTisnek Can you please be more specific which callbacks paragraph and dubious advice you're referring to? I'm guessing that you're talking about the second-to-last paragraph of the answer, where the advice is the sentence about child cancellation? I don't understand why it is dubious, nor how would hoisting the `shield()` note would help at all - after all, the question cannot be resolved just using `shield()` (at least I couldn't think of a way to do it), and the `shield()` reference is just a pointer to another example of the break-the-chain-of-awaits implementation strategy.

Comment: @user4815162342 I was thinking of the shielding action that `shield()` does as something special. But it's not. It's a normal effect of running a function in a separate Task. The special handling here is the propagation of cancels from inner to outer. I don't understand though what the function of this piece is: `if not inner.cancelled(): inner.exception() # Mark inner's result as retrieved.` Why does it need to be marked as retrieved? The docs for `exception()` don't say anything about side effects like this.

Comment: @stach It is likely to suppress the "result of Task xxx was never awaited" warning if it happens that the outer coroutine is canceled and the inner coroutine finishes at the same time (between two awaits). Since the inner task was shielded right until that point, the warning would be spurious, and calling `exception()` is the (undocumented) way of signaling to asyncio that, yes, someone has actually looked at the result.

Comment: Maybe there's a way to create a library around this, so we can use this more easily.

Answer (score 1):

#### Context

First, let's consider the wider context:

`caller() --> your_coro() --> callee()`

You are in control of your coroutine, but not in control of callers and only in partial control of callees.

By default, cancellation is effectively "propagated" both by up and down the stack:

```
(1)
caller1() ------------------+    (2)
                            +--> callee()
caller2() --> your_coro() --+
(4)          (3)
```

In this diagram, semantically and **very loosely**, if `caller1()` is actively cancelled, then `callee()` gets cancelled, and then your coroutine gets cancelled and then `caller2()` gets cancelled. Roughly same happens if `caller2()` is actively cancelled.

(`callee()` is shared, and thus not a plain coroutine, rather a `Task` or a `Future`)

What **alternate behaviour** might you want?

#### Shield

If you want `callee()` to continue even if `caller2()` is cancelled, `shield` it:

```py
callee_f = asyncio.ensure_future(callee())

async def your_coro():
    # I might die, but I won't take callee down with me
    await asyncio.shield(callee_f)
```

#### Reverse shield

If you allow `callee()` to die, but want your coroutine to continue, **convert the exception**:

```py
async def reverse_shield(awaitable):
    try:
        return await awaitable
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        raise Exception("custom")

async def your_coro():
    await reverse_shield(callee_f)
    # handle custom exception
```

#### Shield yourself

This one is questionable — normally you should allow your caller to cancel your coroutine.

A notable exception is when if your caller is a framework, and it's not configurable.

```py
def your_coro():
    async def inner():
        ...
    return asyncio.shield(inner())
```

Comment: This answer doesn't attempt to answer the question, which is specifically about **detecting** whether the callee or caller task was cancelled.

Comment: That's true. This answer attempts to make an educated guess why someone would want to distinguish between callee vs caller cancellation and provide solutions for those cases.

Comment: your example reverse_shield() seems to suffer from the same problem that the OP is trying to avoid -- that is, if your_coro is cancelled (by an unseen canceller) while reverse_shield is awaiting callee_f, then the CancelledError is erroneously swallowed and replaced with Exception("custom") even though callee_f was never cancelled.

Comment: @Sam you may be right, it's been a while since I wrote this. Would you be able to contribute a better answer?

Comment: @Dima I believe user4815162342's implementation of detect_cancel() above is correct; it decouples cancellation of the main task and the subtask. I can't think of a reason why the asyncio authors chose to include shield() but excluded a standard wrapper for this use case, which is not all that unusual.